# Call Powershell from Win 10 CMD, same codes result in different results

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe

variable containing command:

```
set code=$param3 = 'https://edmullen.net/test/rc.jpg'; $c = '$task = $client.GetByteArrayAsync(""' + $param3; $d = '$task = $client.GetByteArrayAsync(""' + $param3;
```

When I run both CMD codes below, I get different results on each time for both, how?

```
start powershell -noexit "%code%"
start powershell -noexit "!code!"
```

Results of $c & $d: (notice the quote mark)

```
PS > $c
$task = $client.GetByteArrayAsync("https://edmullen.net/test/rc.jpg
PS > $d
$task = $client.GetByteArrayAsync(https://edmullen.net/test/rc.jpg
PS >
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it!
Seems to be some powershell bug: The grave accent ` or double quote " to escape a double quote " resulted in the inconsistencies. Using backslash \ to escape works in both cases.

Since I'm calling the powershell code from Win CMD, Microsoft support states to use caret ^ as escape character. 
See similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760545/escape-double-quotes-in-parameter

In this instance, the caret ^ doesn't work to escape the quote either.

```
set code=$param3 = 'https://edmullen.net/test/rc.jpg'; $d = '$task = $client.GetByteArrayAsync(\"' + $param3 + '\"'; $c = '$task = $client.GetByteArrayAsync(\"' + $param3 + '\"';
```

Results in:

```
PS > $c
$task = $client.GetByteArrayAsync("https://edmullen.net/test/rc.jpg"
PS > $d
$task = $client.GetByteArrayAsync("https://edmullen.net/test/rc.jpg"
PS >
```

As a last resort, I would have had to run encoded command as stated in help file:

> -EncodedCommand 
>       Accepts a base-64-encoded string version of a command. Use this parameter
>       to submit commands to Windows PowerShell that require complex quotation
>       marks or curly braces.
>
> To use the -EncodedCommand parameter:
>
> ```
> $command = 'dir "c:\program files" '
> $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
> $encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
> powershell.exe -encodedCommand $encodedCommand
> ```